# Returning/Passing Variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, return

I am a beginning programmer and we were assigned to implement methods into a code. I had this grade average code working fine, but once I broke it up into methods, I could not get the return functions to work. I have tried moving brackets and rearranging the code but to no avail. I believe it may have to do with the scope of my variables... Thanks in advance :)

```
package milsteadgrades;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MilsteadGrades {


public static void main(String[] args)

{
//Call methods to execute program.
displayInfo();
double numOfgrades = getInput();
double average = getAverage(numOfgrades);
char letgrade = determineLetterGrade(average);
displayGrades(average, letgrade);
}


public static void displayInfo()

{
System.out.println("Mallory Milstead");
System.out.println("This program will prompt the user for a number of 
grades"
+ " and each grade. Then the program calculates and displays the average and 
letter"+" grade.");
}

 public static double getInput()

{
//Prompt user to enter number of grades and assign that number to 
numOfgrades.
System.out.print("How many grades would you like to average? ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double numOfgrades = keyboard.nextDouble();
return numOfgrades;
}

public static double getAverage(numOfgrades)

{
//Prompt the user to enter grades.
System.out.println("Enter exam scores : ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double total = 0;
for (double i = 0; i < numOfgrades; i++) {
double grade = keyboard.nextDouble();
total+=grade;}
double average = total/numOfgrades;
return average;
}

public static char determineLetterGrade(average)

{ double testscore = average;
    char letgrade;

    if (testscore >= 90) 
    {
        letgrade = 'A';
    } else if (testscore >= 80) 
    {
        letgrade = 'B';
    } else if (testscore >= 70) 
    {
        letgrade = 'C';
    } else if (testscore >= 60) 
    {
        letgrade = 'D';
    } else 
    {
        letgrade = 'F';
    }
    return letgrade;
    }

public static void displayGrades(average, letgrade)

{
System.out.println("The average of the grades is "+average+ " and the 
letter grade"+ " is " + letgrade+".");}

}
```

Beginning with the line -public static double getAverage(numOfgrades)-, I continuously get "cannot find symbol" error message. None of my variables is being recognized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: Java is NOT modular language. It is an OBJECT language. Hard to say about elegant, or high quality Java code while programming on static methods (de facto violates OP sense)

Comment: Yeah, I am new to this and was a little confused. I should have said implementing methods instead. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the type of the argument of `getAverage`. Like

`public static double getAverage(double numOfgrades)`

Similiarly for your other *methods*(not modules). Have a read of [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) for tips.

Comment: Karl Reid... Thank you so much. I knew it was something simple. I did that and it ran like a charm the first time. You saved me a lot of hassle and time. Best Wishes :)